# How to get the values in split python?

Tags: python

`['column1:abc,def', 'column2:hij,klm', 'column3:xyz,pqr']`

I want to get the values after the `:`. Currently if I split it takes into account column1, column2, column3 as well, which I dont want. I want only the values.
This is similar to key-values pair in dictionary. The only dis-similarity is that it is list of strings.

How will I split it?

**EDITED**

```
user_widgets = Widgets.objects.filter(user_id = user_id)

if user_widgets:
    for widgets in user_widgets:
        widgets_list = widgets.gadgets_list     //[u'column1:', u'column2:', u'column3:widget_basicLine']

        print [item.split(":")[1].split(',') for item in widgets_list]  //yields list index out of range
```

But when the widgets_list value is copied from the terminal and passed it runs correctly.

```
user_widgets = Widgets.objects.filter(user_id = user_id)

if user_widgets:
    for widgets in user_widgets:
        widgets_list = [u'column1:', u'column2:', u'column3:widget_basicLine']

        print [item.split(":")[1].split(',') for item in widgets_list]  //prints correctly.
```

Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Posting this earlier would have been so much nicer all round... What type is `widgets.gadgets_list`... It looks like you're trying to somehow break up the `repr` of a (possibly `gadget`) model object.... Do `print type(gadgets_list)`...

Comment: `print type(widgets_list)`  is `unicode`. and inside database gadgets_list is of type `Charfield`

Comment: @user1162512 I think you need `ast.literal_eval`: `lis = ast.literal_eval(gadgets_list)`

Comment: @user1162512 so in that case `widgets_list` isn't a `list`, it's a string... So.... when you're applying loops to it - you're doing it character by character...

Comment: Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `print repr(widgets_list)` please (I'm hoping it has a length of ~55 chars!)

Comment: @JonClements - Its `u"[u'column1:', u'column2:', u'column3:widget_basicLine']"`

Comment: Then @AshwiniChaudhary is right - use `ast.literal_eval` to make it a list, then the code you've been provided will work

Comment: I tried `widgets_list = widgets.gadgets_list
   lis = ast.literal_eval(widgets_list)
   print [item.split(":")[1].split(',') for item in lis]` it says `global name 'ast' is not defined`. Do I need to import some class. ?

Comment: Thanks all of you for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split items by ":", then split the item with index 1 by ",":

```
>>> l = ['column1:abc,def', 'column2:hij,klm', 'column3:xyz,pqr']
>>> [item.split(":")[1].split(',') for item in l]
[['abc', 'def'], ['hij', 'klm'], ['xyz', 'pqr']]
```

Comment: `1st item` is quite ambiguous, since it has a different meaning in python and in English. I'd rather use `second item`, or `item at index 1` instead.

Comment: `item.partition(':')[2].split(',')` will only split once and guarantees that a blank string will be the result for the `,` split... (which may or may not be what's desired if there is no `:`)

Comment: Well your solution doesnt fits my code, though your works fine. 
When tried on my code it says list index out of range. Wanna apply it on this. `[u'column1:', u'column2:', u'column3:widget_basicLine']`  Its type is `unicode`.

Comment: @user1162512 Works fine for me, list out of index error has nothing to do with unicode strings.

Comment: @user1162512 looks like one of you strings have no ':' in it

Comment: Doesnt why, but it isnt working for me. I'm getting the list from the database, and then printing it in the terminal. After copying that list from the terminal in to the variable `l` I get the correct o/p but when I directly pass the `l` variable , it says list range out of index. Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @user1162512 As Roman has said - one of your strings doesn't have a `:` - see my comment re: `item.partition`

Comment: No. Every item has a `:` in it. Trying `item.partition`.

Comment: `[[u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u':'], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u':'], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u':'], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u''], [u'']]`

Comment: This is what `print [item.partition(':')[2].split(',') for item in widgets_list]` has yielded

Comment: @user1162512: Perhaps you need to post something that looks more like your actual data...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with a 'for' loop and testing if your RH has actual data:

```
li=[u'column1:', u'column2:', u'column3:widget_basicLine', u'column4']
out=[]
for us in li:
    us1,sep,rest=us.partition(':')
    if rest.strip():
        out.append(rest)     

print out    # [u'widget_basicLine']
```

Which can be reduced to a list comprehension if you wish:

```
>>> li=[u'column1:', u'column2:', u'column3:widget_basicLine', u'column4']
>>> [e.partition(':')[2] for e in li if e.partition(':')[2].strip()]
[u'widget_basicLine']
```

And you can further split by the comma if you have data:

```
>>> li=[u'column1:', u'column2:a,b', u'column3:c,d', u'column4']
>>> [e.partition(':')[2].split(',') for e in li if e.partition(':')[2].strip()]
[[u'a', u'b'], [u'c', u'd']]
```